# Connection to database remotely from a server to another differently server

Tags: php, mysql, server-side

I have webhost from ABC Incorporate.

I bought a mysql database from  XYZ Incorporate.

When I try to acces via PHP, the MySQL server from XYZ Incorporate, using the  ABC Incorporate's server, it gives me this error:

> connection refused in

I tried to talk with those two incorporates, and they said that.

No IP restriction was given, so I could've easly connect.
My question is, why is connecting?

My config.php

```
<?php

DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'yes');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWD', 'somepassword');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'IPv4');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'dbname');

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD, DB_NAME);

if(!$con){
    die('Database connection error');
}
?>
```

Comment: Make sure the database is configured to allow network connections, not just local connections.

Comment: This isn't a programming problem in your PHP, it's a database configuration issue. So [dba.se] would be the proper place to ask.

Comment: Most of the time is that the port 3306 is closed to the public at XYZ Incorporate

Comment: Does your new hosting service allow remote connections? Many don't.

Comment: if u are using phpMyadmin to manage your database, then you have to check whether your user account can access database from any host or not.

Answer (score 0):

allow database host to connect remotely.It will be accessible.